Arrays and pointers in C using malloc
I have this code which works. But I'm confused about how pointer arrays work, don't you have to initialize the array? How is this block of code able to just have &arr[i]. Secondly, why don't we need to dereference the pointer to manipulate the data stored in the location the pointer is pointing to (the array)?
int *arr = malloc(size(int)*size);
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    scanf(" %d", &arr[i]);
}

I would've thought that you needed to dereference a pointer in order to manipulate the data it points towards. So I thought this would work:
int *arr = malloc(size(int)*size);
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    scanf(" %d", &*arr[i]);
}

Also, when we're trying to access the array. Why doesn't have a * in front of array[i] work?
//sums value of elements in array
while (i < size ) {
    sum += *array[i];
    i++;
}


size(int) ==> sizeof(int)

The expression *array[i] means get the pointer at the address array[i] and use that (i.e. dereference it) to extract the value. But array is an array of integers, not pointers so the expression is illegal. The compiler should already have told you that.


But I'm confused about how pointer arrays work, dont you have to initialise the array?

Yes, malloc does not provide any initialization.
Yes, this code does some initialization. It uses scanf to read values into all the elements in the allocated memory.

How is this block of code able to just have '&arr[i]'.

Scanf expects the address of the int variable where the converted input shall be stored. Using & gets the address of array alement i.

Secondly, why don't we need to derefernce the pointer to manipulate the data stored in the location the pointer is pointing to (the array)?

You do not want to manipulate the content. You want scanf to do that for you. Therefore you must provide the address.
int *arr = malloc(size(int)*size);
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    scanf(" %d", &arr[i]);
}

This code is likely illegal. What is size(int) supposed to mean? You need sizeof.

I would've thought that you needed to derefrence a pointer in order to manipulate the data it points towards. So I thought this would work:

See above. You don't want to manipulate the data here.
&*arr[i] This does not make sense. & and * cancel each other out.
It is the same as arr[i] which will cause a warning as you must provide an address-

Also, when we're trying to access the array. Why doesn't have a * in front of array[i] work?

//sums value of elements in array
while (i < size ) {
    sum += *array[i];
    i++;
}

Your array does not hold pointers. It holds int values. No need to dereference an int value.
You probably need to revisit your learning material regarding arrays and pointers.


But I'm confused about how pointer arrays work

There's no such thing in your code. There are arrays and there are pointers. In many situations, an array name whenever used in an expression "decays" into the pointer to the first element. And for that same reason we can have an explicitly declared pointer point at the first item in the array too, which is what happens with malloc.

dont you have to initialise the array?

You never have to do that with an array in C no matter how it was allocated. It is often good practice, but in case you are just going to overwrite the contents the first thing you do, then initializing the array is pointless.
The main difference between malloc and calloc is that the latter zero-initializes the array, but for that reason is also slightly slower than malloc.

How is this block of code able to just have &arr[i].  Secondly, why don't we need to deference the pointer to manipulate the data stored in the location the pointer is pointing to (the array)?

It works the same as any array. In fact the [] operator is always applied to a pointer and never to an array. With a plan array declared in local scope int arr[n], then when used in a [] expression, it decays into a pointer (note that [] has higher precedence than &). But in case of dynamic allocation, we already have a pointer so no decay will happen.
Once we have a pointer, the [] operators is defined so that arr[i] is guaranteed to be 100% equivalent to *(arr + i). So it is pointer arithmetic from there, calculating the item index with arr + i, followed by de-referencing. So de-referencing is built in with the [] operator.

Also, when we're trying to access the array. Why doesn't have a * in front of array[i] work?

Because *array[i] is the same as **(array + i) and that won't make any sense.
